# How to horizontal align a section that is out of body's margin to center?

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-float, responsive

I have a section that I'd like to horizontal align but this is what happens:

[image]

I coded the body with the tag "*" so it has 0 margin and 0 padding. So I think that is not the problem, I tried erasing the clearfixes but it won't solved my problem neither. So I'm trapped now because I don't know what it is. I'm a starter here so any help would be nice, thanks.

PS: I forgot to say that it happens only when I'm trying it to be responsive.

This is the HTML of the two parts that I think are mainly causing the problem:

```
   <aside id="lateralBar" class="clearfix">
        <h3>
            Buscar
        </h3>
        <div id="search">
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text">
                <input type="button" value="L" class="icon">
            </form>
        </div>
        <h3>
            Login
        </h3>
        <div id="login" class="lateralBox">
            <form action="">
                <label id="user" class="icon">U</label>
                <input type="email">

                <label id="password" class="icon">w</label>
                <input type="password">

                <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
                <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">

                <a href="#">Registrate aquí</a>
                <a href="#">¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <h3>
            Redes sociales
        </h3>
        <div id="socialNetwork" class="lateralBox">
            <div class="twitter">
                <a href="#" class="icon">t</a>
                <p class="overlay">
                    Twitter
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="facebook">
                <a href="#" class="icon">f</a>
                <p class="overlay">
                    Facebook
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="youtube">
                <a href="#" class="icon">y</a>
                <p class="overlay">
                    Youtube
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3>
            Patrocinadores
        </h3>
        <div id="sponsors" class="lateralBox">

        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Fin aside -->

    <!-- Inicio articulos -->

    <section id="articles" class="clearfix">
        <h2>Últimos artículos</h2>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article id="blog">
            <a href="#">Ir al blog</a>
        </article>
    </section>
```

And this is the CSS for the responsive:

```
@media (max-width: 660px) {
    #banner h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    #lateralBar {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #lateralBar input[type="text"]{
        width: 93%;
    }

    #login input[type="email"],
    #login input[type="password"] {
        width: 90%;
    }

    #articles {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        min-height: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

UPDATE:

This is the previous media query:

```
@media (max-width: 925px) {
    #articles {
        width: 45%;
    }

    #articles .data {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

and the original CSS:

```
/* ARTICLES */

#articles {
    width: 860px;
}

#articles h2 {
    display: block;
    width: 98%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background: url("../img/pxgray.png");
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #393d3f, 1px 2px 0px #393d3f, 2px 3px 0px #393d3f, 3px 4px 0px #393d3f;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 101px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#articles article {
    display: block;
    width: 87.5%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 40px auto;
    margin-left: 101px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "TrebuchetMS";
    background: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ddd;
}

#articles article h4 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 3px auto;
}

#articles article h4 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00538C;
}

#articles article h4 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#articles .data {
    float: right;
    background: #393d3f;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: -5px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#articles .data span {
    margin: 6px;
}

#articles article p {
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a snippet or update the question with all the styles you applied for those sections? I don't think any of the css you shared is the caused for that, so the issue may stands on some other style you applied (perhaps the one outside the @media)

Comment: No worries, anytime :) In case you have different issues and no one is able to lend you a helping hand, you can then just tag me on the qa and I'll be happy to assist if I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a snippet with the code you provided and even though there are still some styles missing, I think I found the reason why you have that alignment off.

The short answer, is that you have some margin-left set on those elements. Try removing `margin-left: 101px;` from the styles applied to `#articles h2` and `#articles article`

Here the snippet with the alignment off:

```css
/* ARTICLES */

#articles {
    width: 860px;
}

#articles h2 {
    display: block;
    width: 98%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background: url("../img/pxgray.png");
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #393d3f, 1px 2px 0px #393d3f, 2px 3px 0px #393d3f, 3px 4px 0px #393d3f;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 101px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#articles article {
    display: block;
    width: 87.5%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 40px auto;
    margin-left: 101px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "TrebuchetMS";
    background: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ddd;
}

#articles article h4 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 3px auto;
}

#articles article h4 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00538C;
}

#articles article h4 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#articles .data {
    float: right;
    background: #393d3f;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: -5px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#articles .data span {
    margin: 6px;
}

#articles article p {
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 925px) {
    #articles {
        width: 45%;
    }

    #articles .data {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 660px) {
    #banner h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    #lateralBar {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #lateralBar input[type="text"]{
        width: 93%;
    }

    #login input[type="email"],
    #login input[type="password"] {
        width: 90%;
    }

    #articles {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        min-height: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<aside id="lateralBar" class="clearfix">
        <h3>
            Buscar
        </h3>
        <div id="search">
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text">
                <input type="button" value="L" class="icon">
            </form>
        </div>
        <h3>
            Login
        </h3>
        <div id="login" class="lateralBox">
            <form action="">
                <label id="user" class="icon">U</label>
                <input type="email">

                <label id="password" class="icon">w</label>
                <input type="password">

                <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
                <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">

                <a href="#">Registrate aquí</a>
                <a href="#">¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <h3>
            Redes sociales
        </h3>
        <div id="socialNetwork" class="lateralBox">
            <div class="twitter">
                <a href="#" class="icon">t</a>
                <p class="overlay">
                    Twitter
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="facebook">
                <a href="#" class="icon">f</a>
                <p class="overlay">
                    Facebook
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="youtube">
                <a href="#" class="icon">y</a>
                <p class="overlay">
                    Youtube
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3>
            Patrocinadores
        </h3>
        <div id="sponsors" class="lateralBox">

        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Fin aside -->

    <!-- Inicio articulos -->

    <section id="articles" class="clearfix">
        <h2>Últimos artículos</h2>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article id="blog">
            <a href="#">Ir al blog</a>
        </article>
    </section>
```

While this is the snippet with everything aligned (I removed the margin-left from those styles):

```css
/* ARTICLES */

#articles {
    width: 860px;
}

#articles h2 {
    display: block;
    width: 98%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background: url("../img/pxgray.png");
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #393d3f, 1px 2px 0px #393d3f, 2px 3px 0px #393d3f, 3px 4px 0px #393d3f;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#articles article {
    display: block;
    width: 87.5%;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "TrebuchetMS";
    background: white;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ddd;
}

#articles article h4 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 3px auto;
}

#articles article h4 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00538C;
}

#articles article h4 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#articles .data {
    float: right;
    background: #393d3f;
    color: white;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: -5px;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#articles .data span {
    margin: 6px;
}

#articles article p {
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-size: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 925px) {
    #articles {
        width: 45%;
    }

    #articles .data {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 660px) {
    #banner h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

    #lateralBar {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #lateralBar input[type="text"]{
        width: 93%;
    }

    #login input[type="email"],
    #login input[type="password"] {
        width: 90%;
    }

    #articles {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        min-height: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<aside id="lateralBar" class="clearfix">
        <h3>
            Buscar
        </h3>
        <div id="search">
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text">
                <input type="button" value="L" class="icon">
            </form>
        </div>
        <h3>
            Login
        </h3>
        <div id="login" class="lateralBox">
            <form action="">
                <label id="user" class="icon">U</label>
                <input type="email">

                <label id="password" class="icon">w</label>
                <input type="password">

                <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
                <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">

                <a href="#">Registrate aquí</a>
                <a href="#">¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?</a>
            </form>
        </div>
        <h3>
            Redes sociales
        </h3>
        <div id="socialNetwork" class="lateralBox">
            <div class="twitter">
                <a href="#" class="icon">t</a>
                <p class="overlay">
                    Twitter
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="facebook">
                <a href="#" class="icon">f</a>
                <p class="overlay">
                    Facebook
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="youtube">
                <a href="#" class="icon">y</a>
                <p class="overlay">
                    Youtube
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h3>
            Patrocinadores
        </h3>
        <div id="sponsors" class="lateralBox">

        </div>
    </aside>

    <!-- Fin aside -->

    <!-- Inicio articulos -->

    <section id="articles" class="clearfix">
        <h2>Últimos artículos</h2>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="data">
                <span>
                    Fecha: 12 de diciembre
                </span>
                <span>
                    Categoría: Pruebas
                </span>
            </div>
            <h4>
                <a href="#">Título del artículo</a>
            </h4>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                </p>
        </article>
        <article id="blog">
            <a href="#">Ir al blog</a>
        </article>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! What happens with that is that when the size is desktop or less than desktop, the article section appears with no margin at all to the left. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I see; I reproduced the snippet on codesandbox so we can easily update it: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-borg-oyy71?file=/index.html - See if this may help (I added the margin on the section and removed it from the children, so it should be now more consistent) - Have a look and let me know if that does